# Issue updating in Zend Framework, it updates before doing all the function

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a web services to connect an app and the website. It supposedly to work syncing only the data that has been changed.

This is the code of the function:

```
public function iphoneexportAction()
{
    echo "Start of IphoneExport<br/>";
    //Basic configuration
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    $data = $this->_request->getParam('udid');
    echo "UDID:".$data;
    if (!$data || $data == '')
    {//no data received
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 7, 'message' => "No UDID value received"));
        $logModel = new Application_Model_WsLog();
        $logDate = array(
            'call_type' => $this->getRequest()->getActionName(),
            'output'    => json_encode(array('status' => 7, 'message' => "No UDID value received")),
            //'input'     => print_r($data,true),
            'input'     => print_r($this->_request,true),);
        $logModel->insert($logDate);
        return true;
    }

    //Taking the user info from the database
    $userModel = new Application_Model_User();
    $user = $userModel->findByEmail($data);
    $userLastSync = $user[0]['sync_ts'];
    echo "<br/>Date from database:".$userLastSync."<br>";

    if (!isset($user[0]))
    {//No user exists with that email
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "user not found."));
        $logModel = new Application_Model_WsLog();
        $logDate = array(
            'call_type' => $this->getRequest()->getActionName(),                                                                                            'output'    => json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "user not found.")),
            //'input'     => print_r($data,true),
            'input'     => print_r($this->_request,true),

        );
        $logModel->insert($logDate);

        return true;
    }

    if ($user[0]['user_type'] != USERTYPE_BRIDE)
    {//User is a bride
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "User type not bride"));
        $logModel = new Application_Model_WsLog();
        $logDate = array(                                                                        
            'call_type' => $this->getRequest()->getActionName(),                                                                                            'output'    => json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'message' => "User type not bride")),                                                         
            //'input'     => print_r($data,true),
            'input'     => print_r($this->_request,true),
        );
        $logModel->insert($logDate);

        return true;
    }

    //Adds user data to the return values
    $return['udid'] = $data;


    /*
     * SETTINGS
     */
    $brideModel = new Application_Model_Bride();

    $bride = $brideModel->findComplete($user[0]['user_id']);
    if($bride[0]['bride_changeTs'] > $userLastSync)
    {
        if(is_null($bride[0]['bride_location_id']))
            $settings['weddingRegion'] = $bride[0]['bride_region_id'];
        else
            $settings['weddingLocation'] = $bride[0]['bride_location_id'];

        $settings['weddingDate'] = is_null(strtotime($bride[0]['bride_weddingDate'])) ? '' : strtotime($bride[0]['bride_weddingDate']);
        $settings['brideName'] = is_null($bride[0]['user_name']) ? '' : $bride[0]['user_name'];
        $settings['bride_groom'] = is_null($bride[0]['bride_groom']) ? '' : $bride[0]['bride_groom'];
        $settings['email'] = is_null($bride[0]['user_email']) ? '' : $bride[0]['user_email'];
        $settings['vendorsCanEmail'] = is_null($bride[0]['bride_vendorsCanEmail']) ? '' : $bride[0]['bride_vendorsCanEmail'];
        $settings['budget'] = is_null($bride[0]['bride_weddingBudget']) ? 0 : $bride[0]['bride_weddingBudget'] / 100;

        $return['settings'] = $settings;
    }
    $mappingModel = new Application_Model_Mapping();


    /*
     * TASKS
     */
    echo "\nStart of tasks";
    $taskModel = new Application_Model_TaskList();
    $tasks = $taskModel->findAllMe($bride[0]['bride_id']);

    $tasktotal = count($tasks);
    $tasknum = 0;

    $taskSend = array();
    foreach ($tasks as $task)
    {
        echo "<br />Task-".$tasknum."---->";          
        echo $task['taskList_changeTs'].' < '.$userLastSync.'';
        if($task['taskList_changeTs'] > $userLastSync)
        {
            echo "--UPDATE";
            $created_on_app = 0;
            /*$mapping = $mappingModel->fetchRow(
                $mappingModel->select()
                ->where('mapping_siteID = :siteID')
                ->where('mapping_type = :type')
                ->where('mapping_userID = :userID')
                ->bind(array(
                    'siteID' => $task['taskList_id'],
                    'type' => MAP_TASK,
                    'userID' => $user[0]['user_id']
                ))                                                                                      
            );*/
            if(empty($mapping))
                $task['taskList_id'] = $task['taskList_id'];
            else
            {
                $task['taskList_id'] = $mapping->mapping_appID;
                $created_on_app = 1;
            }


            $taskActual = array(
                'id' => is_null($task['taskList_id']) ? '' : $task['taskList_id'],
                'name' => is_null($task['taskList_name']) ? '' : $task['taskList_name'],
                'categoryId' => is_null($task['taskList_taskCategory_id']) ? '' : $task['taskList_taskCategory_id']
            );
            switch ($task['taskList_status'])
            {
            case TASKLISTSTATUS_COMPLETED:
                $taskActual['status'] = 1;
                break;
            case TASKLISTSTATUS_TODO:
                $taskActual['status'] = 0;
                break;
            case TASKLISTSTATUS_DELETED:
                $taskActual['status'] = 2;
                break;
            case NULL:
                $taskActual['status'] = 0;
                break;
            }
            //$taskActual['dueDate'] = is_null($task['taskList_date']) ? '' : $task['taskList_date'];
            $taskActual['dueDate'] = $task['taskList_date'];
            $taskActual['notes'] = $task['taskList_comments'];
            $taskActual['created_on_app'] = $created_on_app;
            $taskSend[] = $taskActual;
            //EOF Update if
        }

        $tasknum++;
        //EOF foreach
    }
    if( ! empty($taskSend))
    {
      $return['tasks'] = $taskSend;
      $taskEnded=true;
    }
    echo"<br />";



    /*
    * UPDATE PART
    */
    echo json_encode($return);
    //echo count($return);
    //if(count($return) > 1)
    echo "Task total:".$tasktotal." Tasknum:".$tasknum."<br/>";
    if ($tasktotal == $tasknum&&$taskEnded)
    {       
        $sync_ts_time = time();
        $sync_ts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sync_ts_time);
        $userModel->update(array('sync_ts'=> $sync_ts), array('user_id'=>$user[0]['user_id']));
        echo "UPDATED in the database<br/>";
        echo $sync_ts;
    }
    $logModel = new Application_Model_WsLog();
    $logDate = array(
        'call_type' => $this->getRequest()->getActionName(),
        'output'    => json_encode($return),
        'input'     => print_r($data,true),
    );
    $logModel->insert($logDate);

    return true;

}
```

At the end of the function there is a line which is

```
$userModel->update(array('sync_ts'=> $sync_ts), array('user_id'=>$user[0]['user_id']));
```

This line is causing it not to work. So if I comment it it goes through every task and compares the times, if the time from the database is newer it creates the json data back to the app.
The problem is when I uncomment it, it updates the database timestamp even before starting the foreach.

This is the output when it's commented

```
Start of IphoneExport
UDID:xxxxx@gmail.com
Date from database:2013-09-16 10:49:10
Start of tasks
Task-0---->2013-09-10 13:28:21 < 2013-09-16 10:49:10

Task-80---->2013-09-10 13:28:21 < 2013-09-16 10:49:10
Task-81---->2013-09-18 11:39:15 < 2013-09-16 10:49:10--UPDATE
Task-82---->2013-09-20 14:22:58 < 2013-09-16 10:49:10--UPDATE
{"udid":"xxxxx@gmail.com","settings":{bride settings},"tasks":  [{"id":"22635",task data},   {"id":"22636",task data}]}
Task total:83 Tasknum:83
UPDATE in the database
2013-09-23 10:51:00
```

You can see that it says Data from database 16 September
And only two tasks are updated.
At the end where it says UPDATE in the database is the comented line which updates the last sync to the database.

```
Start of IphoneExport
UDID:xxxxx@gmail.com
Date from database:2013-09-23 11:52:32
Start of tasks
Task-0---->2013-09-10 13:28:21 < 2013-09-23 11:52:32

Task-81---->2013-09-18 11:39:15 < 2013-09-23 11:52:32
Task-82---->2013-09-20 14:22:58 < 2013-09-23 11:52:32
{"udid":"xxxx@gmail.com"}
Task total:83 Tasknum:83
```

You can see that the "Date from database" is the current date, but that is impossible cause it is taken from the database at the beggining and I manually change the date in the database to 16th September.

So it is changing the database without even reaching the update statement so with the new date there is nothing to update in the app.

```
//Taking the user info from the database
    $userModel = new Application_Model_User();
    $user = $userModel->findByEmail($data);
    $userLastSync = $user[0]['sync_ts'];
echo "<br/>Date from database:".$userLastSync."<br>";
```

I am completelly confused, and I can't find why is this happening